# error device-tree: can't request region for resource [mem 0x01c20800-0x01c20aff]

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-tree, orange-pi

**ERROR SHOW:**

```
[  156.303744] blinkled: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  156.303871] blinkled: module verification failed: signature and/or required key  missing - tainting kernel
[  156.304614]  Good ! device probed! 65
[  156.304644] demo_file 1c20800.gpioa7: can't request region for resource [mem 0x01c20800-0x01c20aff]
[  156.304663] demo_file: probe of 1c20800.gpioa7 failed with error -16
[  156.304747] The blinkled driver is success
```

**MY CODE DEVICETREE:**

```dts
gpioa7: gpioa7@1c20800{
        reg = < 0x1c20800 0x300 >;
        clocks = < 0x03 0x36 0x12 0x13 0x00 >;
        clock-names = "apb\0hosc\0losc";
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = < 0x03 >;
        gpios = < 0x0c 0x07 0x01 0x04 >;
        input;
        interrupt-controller;
        #interrupt-cells = < 0x03 >;
        interrupt-parent = < 0x01 >;
        interrupts = < 0x01 0x00 0x48 0x08 >;
        compatible = "gpio,input-pa7-pin";
        status = "okay";
    };
```

**Think error is caused because dts has 2 nodes with same address:**

```dts
soc {
  pinctrl@1c20800 {
    ......
  };
};
```

**But i don't know how to fix it? Thanks!**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The address after the `@` is really only part of the node name. The actual address region will be provided by the `reg` property.